# Add div onclick with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am completely new to Javascript (and Stack Overflow) and I want to build a blog that allows the user to create a div onclick. I referenced [this article on w3shool](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) and tried all the three methods listed. However, the div doesn't show up when I use the first two methods and appears without clicking when I use the third one.

Here's my code for the third method: 
**HTML**

```
<button class="box4" id="newEntry">NEW</button>
```

**Javascript**

```
const parent = document.getElementById("entries");

document.getElementById("newEntry").addEventListener("click", newEntry);

function newEntry() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    parent.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

For the second method, I replaced line 2 with

```
document.getElementById("newEntry").onclick= function () {newEntry()};
```

I have seen similar questions, but none of them solved my problem, so I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Switch to [MDN](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). W3Schools is still pretty outdated.

Comment: you should use event delegation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute and no `DOMContentLoaded` or `load` listener and is not `type="module"`? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: Can you add the template aswell?

Comment: _“appears without clicking when I use the third one”_ — Did you use `object.addEventListener("click", newEntry());`? That’s a beautiful example of how bad W3Schools is. It’s supposed to be `object.addEventListener("click", newEntry);`. The second argument must be a function. W3Schools documents this as `object.addEventListener("click",` _myScript_ `);`, as if you could put arbitrary JS code as an argument…

Comment: Edit: problem solved. There's nothing wrong with the Javascript and the mistake is in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with you code.
It works fine.
just one thing you have to remember: Div by default have no height, so if you want make sure to visualize it, just add height and color to it, like the code bellow.

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("entries");
parent.style.width = '150px';
parent.style.height = '150px';
parent.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

document.getElementById("newEntry").addEventListener("click", newEntry);

function newEntry() {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.style.width = '50px';
    newDiv.style.height = '50px';
    newDiv.textContent = 'Entry';
    newDiv.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    parent.appendChild(newDiv);
}
```

```html
<div id="entries"></div>
<button id="newEntry">new Entry</button>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did add height and width to the new div (I didn't put the css here) and it worked when I called the newEntry function in Javascript, but I can't get it to work if I click.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

You can use `querySelectorAll` with a css selector to query all the elements matching the selector, but you can use the `getElementByName` too. In your example you query the elements by ID, but I don't se where you set the ids.

```js
function onInitClick(){
  const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');
  const secondButton = buttons[1];
  secondButton.addEventListener('click', createButtonAndAppend);
  secondButton.innerText = 'Click me';
}

function createButtonAndAppend(){ 
     const button = document.createElement('button');
     button.addEventListener('click', createButtonAndAppend);
     button.innerText = 'Adds another button';
     document.body.append(button);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onInitClick();">Add click to second button</button> <button>Nothing happens</button>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can do it simply using jquery.

if you want to add something to div,

```
$("#your_div_id").html("your child element")
```

for example

```
<div id="example"></div>

$("#example").html("<h1>Hello world</h1>")
```

then result is

```
<div id="example"><h1>Hello world</h1></div>
```

Comment: This question is unrelated to jQuery. If it’s not tagged [tag:jquery], avoid answering with jQuery.